# Firestore options given that it does not support namespaces

Tags: json, namespaces, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-firestore

Is there anything out there (cloud JSON datastore offering, supporting mobile apps), as performant and feature rich as GCP Firestore in native mode, but provides namespaces?

The lack of this expected feature of Firestore (or any database for that matter), in native mode, is a deal killer all around, due to the nature of the software development cycle, multiple environment needs (dev, test, prod), continuous deployment and delivery pipelines, JSON data models that use namespaces, and much more.

If not, on your really big Firestore project, what are you doing to create development, test, integration environments, or areas, that people can work in, or to support seperately running related applications in production, each needing their own namespace, or set of collections defined, without having to create and manage a bazillion projects, Firestore native instances, and service accounts for each (each project/Firestore instance needs a service account .json file to be created, distributed to developers, securely stored), each additional instance adding more management overhead, ***and*** without having to run Firestore in GCP Datastore mode, in which mode, you lose all the advantages, features and main selling points, that led you to chose Firestore to support your app in the first place?

---

**Optional Reading: Background / Context:**

I recently joined a new project, was asked to create a JSON data model for various services (independently running programs), that comprise the whole, and also setup sample data for multiple runtime environments like 'dev1', 'dev2', 'test', 'prod', where the data model might be in flux, or different in 'dev' or 'test' for a period, until the next production deployment of an updated data model.  I have done this in the past with GCP Datastore, and other databases of all types (NoSQL and Not NoSQL).

At the time, the JSON document store (database), had not been chosen, it was undecided.  While working on the data model, and plan for multiple environments to support development efforts, was told that the datastore to be chosen was Firestore, and subsequently in the process of trying to implement the basic CRUD operations to insert sample data, and create separate sandbox areas in the same Firestore instance where 'dev1' and 'dev2' could work, and be as destructive as they want, within their own area, without affecting each other, have found that namespaces are not supported in native mode (and the client wants native mode, and what is offered there, otherwise they will look at another product for implementation).

And so now, where we thought we would need only two projects, with a Firestore instance, if we stick with Firestore in native mode across the board, we would need thirty six instances.  Because of this, I am seeking input as to what is being done out there to avoid or minimize so many projects/instances.  I have a solution to submit to the company, that involves not using Firestore, but thought I would ask before abandoning this.  We need the ability to segregate, isolate, partition, compartmentalize data for common software development lifecycle needs, and our own application runtime needs, and all the while, in each of these environments, match the production infrastructure as much as possible.

Our need for namespaces, has nothing to do with supporting multiple clients or multitennacy, as is often cited in Google documentation I have found (as seemingly the primary purpose, and the only use case for this), and historically, that is one less frequently implemented use case of namespaces, out of many hundreds more.

We only want a max two projects and database instances (two Firestore native instances):

1. Production
2. Everything else under the sun that is not production: 'dev1',
   'dev2', 'test1', 'test2', 'tmp-test-whatever'

With any database product, you should need only one database instance, and have a mechanism to support segregation and isolation of data, and data definitions, creating as many namespaces, as you want, within that database.  Some database products refer to each namespace as a database.  I want to distinguish here between the runtime software I am calling a "database", or "database instance", and the area where data is defined and contained (the namespace).

Oracle, PostgreSQL and others, call these segregated areas "schemas".  Other data formats, XML and many more support the notion of "namespaces", so as to provide isolation and avoid data collisions of definitions with the same name.

Google Datastore supports namespaces, they say for multiple tenancy, but in such a way that each namespace is not isolated, protected as is with other database products.  Any person that has access to that Datastore instance, can do anything with ALL namespaces, and there is no way to create a service account that restricts entirely, or limits access to a particular namespace.

With this Firestore backed project in production, there will be multiple separatly running services at any one time hitting, what we had hoped to be a single Firestore instance in native mode.  Some will run on mobile, some will run on another VM instance (Web app initiated CRUD opertations on various collections/documents).  All services are part of the same product.  Some of these separate services have collections with the same name.

Example: a 'users' collection:

```
   { service1:      <== 'service1' is the namespace, it has multiple collections, 'users' which is just one for example.
      { users:
         { user: {
            login:  <login_name>
            <other fields>:
         }
      }
    }
```

Now another name space, that also has a 'users' collection, with a different data definition, and different set of data from the above

```
{ service2:     <== 'service2' is the name space
  { users:
     { user: {
        first_name: <first_name>
        last_name:  <last_name>
        <other fields>:
     }
  }
}
----
and other services that have their own collections.
```

Other use cases for namespaces, as I have mentioned above:

1. environment, like 'dev', or 'test' for example, for use in modification of any collection, such as adding, reworking the data model during development.

   a unit test we want to write, that would insert data in a unique name space devoted temporarily to just that test, data would be inserted, the test would run, and at the end all data belonging to that temporary namespace would be deleted.

   a namespace used by the mobile app portion of the product

   a namespace to support the web app portion of the product, we are trying to use one datastore product for the entire product

   a namespace environment for CI to do various things

I proposed something that would work for the data model in Firestore native mode, but it is very undesirable and kludgy, like having the service name and environment in the collection name:   dev1_service1_users, dev1_service2_users, and so on to distinguish, and avoid collisions.

Firestore native gives you one namespace, they call default, but it is not a name space at all, it is a complete absence of one.

The only solution I see is to not use Firestore, but some other JSON datastore that would get us close to what Firestore native offers, a solution we would install, update and manage on a VM in the cloud, and manage all that infrastructure (load balancing, +much more).

I will post the direction we take, for anyone interested, or having a similar problem or discussion.